# The differential equations $d\vec{y}/dx=\vec{f}(x,\vec{y},\vec{\lambda}),\vec{y_0}=\vec{f}(x_0)$ has $x_0,\lambda,x\in C^k$ if $\vec{f}\in C^k(D)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Define:

$$\vec{y}_:=(y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_n), ~~~ \vec{f}_:=(f_1,f_2,\cdots,f_n),$$

$\vec{\lambda}_:=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots,\lambda_3)$ are the parameters of the differential equations.

$$d\vec{y}/dx=\vec{f}(x,\vec{y},\vec{\lambda}),~~~ \vec{y_0}=\vec{f}(x_0)$$ is a group of differential equations which mean \begin{align}
dy_1/dx&=f_1(x,y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_n,\vec{\lambda}),\\
dy_2/dx&=f_2(x,y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_n,\vec{\lambda}),\\
\cdots,\\
dy_n/dx&=f_n(x,y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_n,\vec{\lambda})
\end{align} and satisfying the initial condition $y_{01}=f_1(x_0),\cdots,y_{0n}=f_n(x_0)$. Suppose $x\in D$, $\vec{y} \in \Omega$, $\vec{\lambda}\in \Lambda $. If $\vec{f} \in C^k(D \times\Omega\times\Lambda)$ (where $C^k $ means the derivative of $k$ order is still continuous in the definition domain), then we can have $x,x_0 \in C^k(D)$, $\vec{y_0} \in C^k(\Omega)$, $\lambda \in C^k(\Lambda)$.

When $k=0,1$, it's also not trivial, but it has been proved by me.

I have an intuition that the proof may involve the variational equation (matrix).

It's a really interesting problem, have a challenge or show your ideas！

Comment: I have the impression that you are posting this because you have the solution and find it interesting- is that the case?

Comment: Your domains make no sense. You are looking for solutions $y\in C^k(I\to\Omega)$, $I\subset D$. What sense does it make that the constant parameters are $C^k$? What you probably mean is that in $y(x)=\phi(x;x_0,y_0,λ)$ one has $\phi\in C^k(I\times D_0\times Ω_0\times Λ_0)$ where the sets are sufficiently small subsets around the point-of-interest.